# Eclipse - Not able to code as Java Application with Rest Assured Framework

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

I was trying to Automate Rest APIs with Rest Assured framework and as part of this selected google place search API and tried to run. But, seeing error

I have tried adding the certificate from command prompt to the cacerts file but didn't work out

```
public class Rest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        RestAssured.baseURI= "https://maps.googleapis.com";

    given().        
        param("input","Museum%20of%20Contemporary%20Art%20Australia").
        param("inputtype","textquery").
        param("fields","photos,formatted_address,name,rating,opening_hours,geometry").
        param("key", "AIzaSfyDyn2l_QUZz7RT5MseFIrItuCdBR3drpaJU ").

        when().
        get("/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/xml").

    then().assertThat().statusCode(200);




    }

}
```

Expected that script should run

Actual - Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Sounds like you have enabled `HTTPS` without providing a certificate.

Comment: @TheHeadRush How I can provide certificate for the above?